# Which font types i will need in @face-font and how to to make font smoother in all browser like sIFR?

Tags: css, xhtml, sifr, font-face

Which font types i will need in @face-font and how to to make font smoother in all browser like sIFR?

IE 6, IE 7, IE 8, Firefox 3+, Google Chrome and Safari (MAC)

Which font type i needed

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/325648/11032963642-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/325648/11032963642-My-Desktop.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using font-squirrel, so you should be uploading an OpenType font. You can also upload a TTF SVG you can untick as that's for iPhone support. Depending on the kerning, you may want to add:

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=UserSubmitted/fonts/hIEfix.png,sizingMethod=crop); zoom:1;

to your CSS declaration for the place you're using the font to enable/disable cleartype rendering, which makes some PC fonts look great and some look awful, depending on the individual font's hinting.

You should also be using the bulletproof (smiley varient) css invocation for best results and healthy syntax-based approach.

Comment: pls explain ur first paragraph in detail.

Comment: okay: Opentype fonts based on our experiences tend to have more consistent hinting and character sets than the truetype fonts, and windows opentype fonts are usually a superset of a truetype font. I missed a "." after TTF and before SVG, but it doesn't hurt to leave SVG font support in for the iPhone OS.

The filter is an IE-only (DirectX) which is triggered by zoom:1 (essentially a hasLayout equivalent), and efficiently provides an alpha channel for fonts which wouldn't otherwise use one. MS's language-based (eg. GDI, GDI+) font smoothing is mixed, so there's not a single use solution.

Comment: I suggest the four font types you have ticked in the screenshot(this is somewhat out of the scope of the original question). 

If you're actually referring to fonts, then you could try fonts from fontfont, fontspring and other reputable, web-aware foundries. Generally speaking the more you pay for a font, the better hinting is.